# When is shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier called?

Tags: ios

I created a segue from a button (ctrl-drag) from one scene to another in the storyboard. I also created an `IBAction` connected to the same button. In the View controller where I implemented the `IBAction` I also implemented `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`.

When I run it `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` is called first and second the `IBAction`.

However, I have an old project with the same setup where the `IBAction` is called before `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier`.

Is there a specific order these two methods are called? Is there any way to change that order?

In another similar post the answer suggests to call `shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier` from the `IBAction`. Is that a good practice?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have both an IBAction and a segue from the button?  Generally you would only do one or the other.

Comment: Good point. Maybe I can just remove the IBAction. Is it common to call shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier from another method? Or is it one of those methods that only the system calls?

Comment: It's reasonably common to call it yourself when triggering a segue from code since calling `performSegueWithIdentifier` from code doesn't result in the system calling it for you.

Comment: @dan No, you never ever call `shouldPerformSegue`! If you didn't want the segue, you would not have called `performSegue` in the first place!!!

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @matt It's fine to call it yourself IMO in cases where the same segue can be triggered both from the storyboard and code and you want to centralize all your logic in `shouldPerformSegue`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I run it shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier is called first and second the IBAction

Only one of them should be called. The fact that they are both called means that your storyboard configuration is incorrect (in *both* cases).

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what could be incorrect in the storyboard. I just used ctrl-drag to create the segue and the IBAction. I thought it was the standard why to do it.

Comment: Either the button automatically triggers the segue (in the storyboard) or it calls into code to perform the segue (using the IBAction). Not both.

Comment: Thanks. I'll remove the IBAction. Thinking it again, I don't really need it.

Comment: Note that you should only use the segue directly attached to a button if the *only* thing you have to do is pass data to the destination view controller via `prepareForSegue`.  if there is anything else that you need to do, especially server calls, you would want to set up the IBAction, perform the necessary actions, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier`, using a segue that you create by ctrl + dragging from the left most icon that appears when you hover your mouse over the top of a view controller on the storyboard.

Comment: Thanks @JakeT. I think that's exactly what I need to do as I am downloading data from a server. So I should call performSegueWithIdentifier from the IBAction. Although I may even need to use multi-threading because I'll have to wait for the data to download. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, any server call is going to be asynchronous. You'll want to put the `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:];` call inside of the success handler for that server call, instead of calling it in the main scope of the IBAction.